# Pandas: Merge dataframes and keep only the minimum value associated with merged unique pairs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I'm having a tougher problem with pandas.

I am merging two dataframes on a column `V` which defines groups.

Both dataframes have also a unique `ID` column and a `Time` column.

After merging I compute the `Timedelta` between those two columns and filter out the negative values:

```
import pandas as pd

L11 = ['V1','V1','V1','V2','V2','V3','V3','V3','V3']
L12 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
L13 = [pd.Timestamp("1.1.1980 12:12:12"),
       pd.Timestamp("1.1.1980 13:12:12"),
       pd.Timestamp("1.2.1980 01:12:12"),
       pd.Timestamp("1.1.1980 14:12:12"),
       pd.Timestamp("1.1.1980 16:12:12"),
       pd.Timestamp("1.1.1980 16:12:12"),
       pd.Timestamp("1.1.1980 14:12:12"),
       pd.Timestamp("1.1.1980 13:12:12"),
       pd.Timestamp("1.2.1980 10:12:12")]

L21 = ['V1','V1','V2','V3','V3','V3','V3','V3','V3']
L22 = [11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19]
L23 = [pd.Timestamp("1.1.1980 12:12:12"),
       pd.Timestamp("1.1.1980 13:12:12"),
       pd.Timestamp("1.1.1980 14:12:12"),
       pd.Timestamp("1.1.1980 14:12:12"),
       pd.Timestamp("1.1.1980 16:12:12"),
       pd.Timestamp("1.1.1980 18:12:12"),
       pd.Timestamp("1.1.1980 11:12:12"),
       pd.Timestamp("1.1.1980 12:12:12"),
       pd.Timestamp("1.2.1980 10:12:12")]

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'V':L11,'ID1':L12,'Time1':L13})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'V':L21,'ID2':L22,'Time2':L23})

df = pd.merge(df1,df2,on='V')
df["Delta"] = df.Time1-df.Time2
df = df[df.Delta>pd.Timedelta(0)].copy()
df = df.drop(["Time1","Time2"],axis=1)
```

Additionally I count how many entries per `V`-group there are in each dataframe and get the lower value which I'm calling `Max` because it will be the maximum allowed value of merged entries per group. This ensures that on both sides the `ID`-values per `V`-group can be unique.

```
df1g = df1.groupby("V").ID1.count().reset_index().rename(columns={"ID1":"C1"})
df2g = df2.groupby("V").ID2.count().reset_index().rename(columns={"ID2":"C2"})
df12g = pd.merge(df1g,df2g,on='V')
df12g["Max"] = df12g[["C1","C2"]].min(axis=1)
df = pd.merge(df,df12g[['V','Max']],on='V')
df = df.sort_values(['V','Delta']).reset_index(drop=True)
```

This is my sorted example data:

```
     V  ID1  ID2    Delta  Max
0   V1    2   11 01:00:00    2
1   V1    3   12 12:00:00    2
2   V1    3   11 13:00:00    2
3   V2    5   13 02:00:00    1
4   V3    8   18 01:00:00    4
5   V3    6   14 02:00:00    4
6   V3    7   18 02:00:00    4
7   V3    8   17 02:00:00    4
8   V3    7   17 03:00:00    4
9   V3    6   18 04:00:00    4
10  V3    6   17 05:00:00    4
11  V3    9   16 16:00:00    4
12  V3    9   15 18:00:00    4
13  V3    9   14 20:00:00    4
14  V3    9   18 22:00:00    4
15  V3    9   17 23:00:00    4
```

- Group `V1` has 3 entries but is only allowed 2
- Group `V2` has 1 entry and is only allowed 1
- Group `V3` has 12 entries but is only allowed 4

I now need to find for each `ID1` the `ID2` entry with the lowest `Delta` but the combinations must be unique.

That means because in line `4` `ID1 8` is paired with `ID2 18` in line `6` `ID1 7` must not be paired with `ID2 18`.

The result I want is essentially this:

```
     V  ID1  ID2    Delta  Max
0   V1    2   11 01:00:00    2
1   V1    3   12 12:00:00    2
3   V2    5   13 02:00:00    1
4   V3    8   18 01:00:00    4
5   V3    6   14 02:00:00    4
8   V3    7   17 03:00:00    4
11  V3    9   16 16:00:00    4
```

And I can't wrap my head around how to achieve this.

Simple approaches like

```
df1 = df.drop_duplicates('ID1')
df2 = df.drop_duplicates('ID2')
result = pd.merge(df1,df2)
```

obviously don't work out properly.

Is it even possible to solve this without iterating over the sorted rows and building a memory of already occupied `ID2`-values?

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question with the `iterrows()` approach:

After the line

```
df = df.sort_values(['V','Delta']).reset_index(drop=True)
```

this solves the problem:

```
df["Keep"] = False
old_V = ''
for i,row in df.iterrows():
    if row.V != old_V:
        old_V = row.V
        ID1_list = []
        ID2_list = []
    if row.ID1 not in ID1_list and row.ID2 not in ID2_list:
        df.iloc[i,5] = True
        ID1_list.append(row.ID1)
        ID2_list.append(row.ID2)
df = df[df.Keep].drop("Keep",axis=1)
```